# Why is $Q$ a division group under addition, and not multiplication?

Tags: group-theory

I read a Wikipedia article which said that $Q$ is a divisible group under addition.

What does the phrase "under addition" imply here? Isn't $Q$ a divisible group under multiplication too? Isnt $Z$ a divisible group under addition?

Here is what I understand from "divisible group under addition": for any natural number $n$ and any element $x\in G$, there exists an element $y\in G$ such that $n+y=x$.

Comment: That's not the definition of divisible group. WIth the right definition, the issue will become clear.

Comment: To say that an abelian additive group $(G,+)$ is divisible means for any natural number $n$ and any element $x\in G$, there exists an element $y\in G$ such that $ny=x$ (i.e., $y + \cdots + y = x$).

Comment: Analogously, to say that a mutliplicative group $(G,\cdot)$ is divisible means for any natural number $n$ and any element $x\in G$, there exists an element $y\in G$ such that $y^n=x$ (i.e., $(y) \cdots (y) = x$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

1) In a group any element has an inverse. What is the inverse, with respect to multiplication, of $0$ (the neutral element for addition in $\mathbb{Q}$)?)

2) If you take the set $\{\mathbb{Q}-0\}$ with multiplication, there is a rational number $x$ such that $x^2=2$ (as required for a [divisible group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group))?

Answer (score 1):

For a ring $R$, a divisible $R$-module $M$ is one in which for every $m\in M$ and $r\in R$, there exists an $m'\in M$ such that $m=rm'$.

A divisible group is the special case where you view an additive abelian group as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. So viewing $\mathbb{Q}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, it will be a divisible $\mathbb{Z}$-module if for every $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, there exists $q'\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $q=nq'$, since the $\mathbb{Z}$-action on $\mathbb{Q}$ is by multiplication. This is of course true by taking $q'=\frac{q}{n}$.

On the other hand, $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a group under multiplication, so it can't be a divisible group under multiplication.